# Cp files into subdirectory with find -exec

Tags: grep, find, exec

Why is this command not copying the 17 `.png` files into a sub-directory within  my current directory?

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -3 | wc -l
17
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -3 -print0 | grep -z loader | xargs -r0 cp -t ./user_name_tutorial/
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -3 -print0
../Plugins.png./Screenshot from 2015-08-06 22:30:56.png./Screenshot from 2015-08-06 22:28:21.png./Plugins_ex-in-post.png./Screenshot from 2015-08-06 22:31:14.png./Pages_visit_site.png./user_name_tutorial./Page_edit.png./Screenshot from 2015-08-06 22:28:52.png./Page_edit-visual.png./Plugins-google-maps_v2-example.png./Screenshot from 2015-08-06 22:29:27.png./Plugin_google_apps.png./Screenshot from 2015-08-06 22:30:44.png./Media_uploads.png./Plugins_add_new.pnguser_name@COMP_NAME-X:~/Pictures$
```

Comment: So how many `.png` files did it actually copy?  What is `grep -z loader` intended for?

Comment: please disregard the `grep loader` command that was a former file name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're showing us the output of

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -3 -print0
```

What's the output of

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -3 -print0 | grep -z loader
```

?  I don't see any file names containing the word `loader`
in the output that you did show. 
If the output from the `grep` (which is the input to `xargs`) is nothing,
then, naturally, nothing will be copied.

---

Also,

- Rather than `find … | grep foo`,
  you can say `find … -name "*foo*"` and save a process.
  Except:

  > I notice that you used `-maxdepth 1`, which (as you know)
  >   restricts the search to the current directory. 
  >   Without that, `find` would look into subdirectories,
  >   and `find … | grep foo` would give you *all* files
  >   in any subdirectory named `food_fight`, `football`, or `pound_foolish`,
  >   regardless of the *file's* name,
  >   since the `grep` would be looking at the entire (**`.`**-relative) pathname,
  >   rather than just the filename.
- `-maxdepth 1` doesn't prevent `find` from reporting
  the names of subdirectories in the current directory —
  so, if you had a subdirectory named `loader` (or `other_loader_files`),
  *its name* would be passed to `cp` —
  which would just get you an error message, since you didn't say `cp -r`,
  but there might be similar situations where that could catch you by surprise
  and do something nasty.
- You can avoid the above (potential) problem by saying `-type f`.
- I realize that you used `-mtime -3`,
  which (as you know) restricts the search based on modification date. 
  Note that, if you weren't using a search-restricting test
  such as `-mtime -3` or `-type f`,
  using `find … -maxdepth 1` is pretty much equivalent to using a wildcard
  (commonly known as a "glob" or a filename expansion pattern), as in

  ```
  cp -t ./user_name_tutorial/ *loader*
  ```

  or

  ```
  cp *loader* ./user_name_tutorial/
  ```

Comment: The other guy makes a valid point — if doesn't make sense to use `-print0` when you're just writing `find`'s output to the terminal for debugging purposes.